# How to get the log folder path of a certain IIS Application/Site in VBScript

Tags: iis, iis-7, vbscript, asp-classic

I am looking for a way to find the log folder path of a certain website in IIS by its ID name, like: `W3SVC1` or any other method, from inside my application.  Is this possible? I tried looking up and down google and found nothing. How is this achieved?

The following code works, but only gets all of the application names/ids (like `W3SVC/1`), i need the actual log file path, and since they can change I don't want to use the static default log file directory as the root on this:

```
    Function ProcessWebSite(ServiceType, SiteNumber)
    Set IISWebSite = getObject("IIS://localhost/" & ServiceType & "/" & SiteNumber)
    Set IISWebSiteRoot = getObject("IIS://localhost/" & ServiceType & "/" & SiteNumber & "/root")
    ProcessWebSite = IISWebSite.ServerComment
    Set IISWebSiteRoot = nothing
    Set IISWebSite = Nothing
    end function

    Function ShowSites(ServiceType, ClassName, Title)
    Response.write "Web Sites Description=" & "<br>"
    Response.write "===============================================================" & "<br>"
    Set IISOBJ = getObject("IIS://localhost/" & ServiceType)
    for each Web in IISOBJ
    if (Web.Class = ClassName) then
    Response.write Ucase(ServiceType) & "/" & Web.Name & _
    Space(17-(len(Ucase(ServiceType))+1+len(Web.Name))) & " " & _
    ProcessWebSite(ServiceType, Web.name) & "<br>"
    end if
    next
    Set IISOBj=Nothing
    End function

    Call ShowSites("w3svc", "IIsWebServer", "Web")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function Returnlog(WebSitePath)
    Dim statut
    Set IISOBJRoot = getObject(webSitePath)
    Returnlog = IISOBJRoot.LogFileDirectory
    set IISOBJRoot = Nothing
end Function

IIsObjectPath = "IIS://localhost/w3svc"
Set IIsObject = GetObject(IIsObjectPath)
for each obj in IISObject
    if (Obj.Class = "IIsWebServer") then
        BindingPath = IIsObjectPath & "/" & Obj.Name
        Set IIsObjectIP = GetObject(BindingPath)

        WScript.Echo IISObjectIP.ServerComment & ": " & Returnlog(IISObjectIP.ADSPath) & vbnewline
        'WScript.Echo IISObjectIP.LogType & vbnewline

    end if
next
```